# How to show a subview of xib into table cell load from another xib

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xib, subview

i've got problem with load xib subview [TestSummaryView] into table cell [NotesTableCell]load from xib file. My xib subview is visible only after refresh cell by drag out of the screen.

MainFile.m:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

NotesTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NotesTableCell"];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NotesTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = __noteTableCell;
    self.__noteTableCell = nil;
}

(...)

for (UIView* view in [cell.summaryView subviews])
    [view removeFromSuperview];

UIView* view = [note.form summaryView];
[cell.summaryView addSubview:view];
view.bounds = cell.summaryView.bounds;
view.center = CGPointMake(cell.summaryView.bounds.size.width/2, cell.summaryView.bounds.size.height/2);

[cell.webView setHidden:YES];
[cell.summaryView setHidden:NO];                               
}
```

TestForm.m

```
-(UIView*)summaryView 
{
if (!_testSummaryView) 
{
    NSArray* xib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestSummaryView" owner:self options:nil];
    _testSummaryView = [[xib objectAtIndex:0] retain];
}

(...)

return _testSummaryView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was in other part of code.